# "Taking a jolt from" meaning in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, analogy

I am studying a video about global warming, the professor starts with this expression:
"So fossil fuel combustion is​ ​basically **taking a jolt** **from** that battery of the biosphere." Which, I am struggling with what it really means.

Here are the following sentences so that you could get the context.

"We're digging up some​ buried organic carbon and reacting with oxygen,​to get the energy back. So one thing that may occur to you​ is does that mean we're going to use up the oxygen in the atmosphere? That would be like draining the battery​ of the biosphere all the way dead. Fortunately for us, most of the buried​ organic carbon in the earth is in an inconvenient​ form to use as a fuel."

My first guess was: The combustion of fossil fuel is sucking away the essence from the powerhouse of the biosphere, and it is getting weaker as time goes.

Could you confirm I am in the right direction of thinking this way?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you've looked up the word "jolt" and seen that it [means](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jolt) a shock or a sudden movement. But in the context you quoted in your question, a "jolt" is a burst of energy. That's why there is an [energy drink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jolt_Cola) with the same name. As you can see from the link, the can for this drink was quite hilariously designed to resemble a battery.

The professor is saying that fossil fuels get a burst of energy from the biosphere: the energy comes from oxygen, which combines with fossil fuels to start a combustion reaction.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is brilliant.